# Example of discontinuous complex-valued function which satisfies hypotheses of Morera's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ which is discontinuous at some point, but has the property that
$$\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0$$
for every closed piecewise smooth curve $\gamma\subset \mathbb C$?

Morera's theorem states that if $f$ is continuous and satisfies the above property, then it is holomorphic. I'm interested in knowing how required the condition of continuity in the assumption is, but couldn't think of a counterexample.

EDIT: After some helpful comments, I have better formulated my question as the following:

> Is there an example of a discontinuous function $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$, which cannot be modified on a set of measure zero (under Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb C$) to make it continuous, such that its contour integral over every closed piecewise smooth curve is $0$?

Comment: $f(z)=1$ if $z=0$ and $f(z)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: I'm feeling very foolish now. Thank you!

Comment: @Aloizio But might there be a non-trivial example, i.e. a function whose equivalence class in $L^1$ does not contain a continuous function?

Comment: @Milind When we talk about $L^1(\mu)$, $\mu$ is assumed to be a positive measure. Here each path $\gamma$ defines a complex measure on its domain $[a,b]$ by $dz = \gamma'(t) dt$. I wonder which $L^1$ you are referring to.

Comment: @QiyuWen You are right, my statement wasn't precise. What I mean is this: 

Is there an example of a discontinuous function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, which cannot be modified on a set of measure zero (under Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb C$) to make it continuous, such that its contour integral over every closed piecewise smooth curve is 0?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious example is $f(z) = 1/z^2$, which having a primitive in the punctured disc, satisfies the condition that
$$\oint_\gamma f(z) dz = 0$$
for all piecewise smooth and closed $\gamma$, but is non-trivially discontinuous at $z=0$.